# MySQL delete rows based on value and after a timestamp for each customer

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete rows after a timestamp for each customer who have value 1 in MySQL. Example table:

`id     | timestamp           | cust_ID | value
899900 | 2016-04-11 12:00:00 | 500219  | 0
899901 | 2016-04-12 16:00:00 | 500219  | 0
899902 | 2016-04-14 11:00:00 | 500219  | 1
899903 | 2016-04-15 12:00:00 | 500219  | 1
899904 | 2016-04-23 09:00:00 | 500219  | 0
899905 | 2016-05-02 19:00:00 | 500219  | 0
909901 | 2016-04-12 16:00:00 | 500230  | 0
909902 | 2016-04-14 11:00:00 | 500230  | 1
909903 | 2016-04-15 12:00:00 | 500230  | 1
909904 | 2016-04-23 09:00:00 | 500230  | 0
909905 | 2016-05-02 19:00:00 | 500230  | 0
939905 | 2016-05-02 19:00:00 | 500240  | 0`

Trying to achieve:

`id     | timestamp           | cust_ID | value
899900 | 2016-04-11 12:00:00 | 500219  | 0
899901 | 2016-04-12 16:00:00 | 500219  | 0
899902 | 2016-04-14 11:00:00 | 500219  | 1
899903 | 2016-04-15 12:00:00 | 500219  | 1
909901 | 2016-04-12 16:00:00 | 500230  | 0
909902 | 2016-04-14 11:00:00 | 500230  | 1
909903 | 2016-04-15 12:00:00 | 500230  | 1
939905 | 2016-05-02 19:00:00 | 500240  | 0`

So far I have the following which throws error 1242 'subquery returns more than one row':

`CREATE VIEW max_id AS SELECT id, cust_ID, MAX(timestamp) FROM table WHERE value = 1 GROUP BY cust_ID;
DELETE FROM max_id WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM max_id GROUP BY cust_ID);`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% what the exactly logic you want is.  But, you should be able to use a `join`.  The following deletes all rows for a customer whose timestamp is greater than the maximum timestamp with a "1" for that customer:

```
delete t
    from table t join
         (select t.cust_Id, max(timestamp) as maxts
          from table t
          group by t.cust_id
         ) tt
         on t.cust_id = tt.cust_id and tt.timestamp > t.timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This only keeps one row per cust_id however. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works now, I switched the tt.timestamp > t.timestamp. Thanks!